# How to Dynamically Add "Remarks" Column Comment against Retrieved Records in a Gridview using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am doing a multiple column search through checkboxes to retrieve data in a gridview. I have to add another column "Remarks" against retrieved records. Under the Remarks column comments are added against each record that has been retrieved on the basis of their respective checkboxes. But there is a issue, a record can be retrieved through more than one check at a time. Lets say, if Country is "XYZ" and Finance Date < Invoice Date then both should be mentioned in the cell under newly created Remarks column. Moreover, i have to check empty cells or invalid data entered in cells to be mitigated by exception handling. I have been trying to resolve these two issue but i am not successful.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace FileUploadApplication
{
    
    public partial class RFS : Form
    {
        public static DataTable dt;
        
        public RFS()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        private void RFS_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView2.DataSource = Form1.dataRecord;
            SerialNumber();

        }
        private void SerialNumber() {
            //Adding Serial number
            DataGridViewTextBoxCell newCell = new();
            DataGridViewColumn SNOCol = new(newCell);
            SNOCol.DisplayIndex = 0;
            SNOCol.HeaderText = "S.NO.";
            SNOCol.Name = "SNO";
            dataGridView2.Columns.Add(SNOCol);
            
            int cnt = dataGridView2.Rows.Count;
            int i;
            for (i = 1; i <= cnt; i++)
            {
                dataGridView2.Rows[i - 1].Cells["SNO"].Value = i;
            }
        }
        private void Remarks()
        {
            //Adding Remarks
            DataGridViewTextBoxCell newCell = new();
            DataGridViewColumn Remarks = new(newCell);
            Remarks.DisplayIndex = 50;
            Remarks.HeaderText = "Remarks";
            Remarks.Name = "Remarks";
            dataGridView2.Columns.Add(Remarks);
            
        }

       private void LoadSNumber()
        {
            int i=1;
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows)
            {
                row.Cells["SNO"].Value = i;i++;
            }
        }

        private void label1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Btn_Search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            { 
                { 
                  dt = Form1.dataRecord;
                  DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
                  var CountryFilter = "";
                  var AmountFilter = "";
                  var DateFilter = "";
                  var Operator = " or ";                
                  foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                 {
                   if (Chk_CoS != null & Chk_CoS.Checked == true)
                   {
                        CountryFilter = "[COUNTRY OF SHIPMENT] = 'XYZ';  
                   }

                if (Chk_Amount != null & Chk_Amount.Checked == true)
                {

                    AmountFilter = "[BILL AMOUNT] < [AMOUNT FINANCED]";
                }

                if (Chk_Date != null & Chk_Date.Checked == true)
                {
                    DateFilter = "[Date of Finance] < [InvoiceDate]";
                }
            
                var Filter = (CountryFilter == "" ? "" : CountryFilter + (AmountFilter == "" ? "" : Operator)) + (AmountFilter == "" ? "" : AmountFilter + (DateFilter == "" ? "" : Operator)) + DateFilter;
                dv.RowFilter = Filter;
                dataGridView2.DataSource = dv;
                LoadSNumber();
               }
            Remarks();
            //Comments(dtt);
        }
        private void Chk_Date_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           
        }

        private void Chk_Amount_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Chk_CoS_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void dataGridView2_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            
        }

      }
   }
}
```

Comment: But what row and where is the remarks data to be stored in the database? Those remarks have to be some place and some where in the database? Are the remarks a column in the table, or is this a related child table. That child table and each row of remarks can only in a typical database belong to one parent record - any other design will break relational data rules.  You fail to explain where, and what table these remarks to belong to, and more important how your data tables are setup to relate these remakes to a given row in that grid.  A correct data schema is required before you can code this

Comment: Basically the purpose this project is just to  upload an Excel file into a gridview and then record retrieval by applying various conditions through checkboxes. I am not storing any file into the database. I have two forms, one which is used for uploading excel file and another which has multiple conditions for search. The Remarks function has added an additional column into the gridview but the inserting remarks against each retrieved record into the remarks column is a bit confusing for me.

Comment: Filtering the rows of data is 100% separate issue from a user deciding to type some text into a text box. The user is free to type in text into any text box for each row. Then you process the data in all the grid rows with single submit button. I don't see the issue here. Only confusing part is that somehow, some text out of the blue typed into one text box row is also now supposed to appear or be transferred to some other row and text box also? You can certainly do this - but it seems strange. A event to text box change event is possible, and I guess it could copy that text to another row.